# If $(a_n),\ (b_n)$ are positive decreasing sequences, $(a_n)$ is convex, $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum b_n$ diverges, then $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Start by considering [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/if-a-n-subset0-infty-is-non-increasing-and-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-infty) Is an attempt to generalise the role of $\ f_1(n)=n\ $ to $\ f_2(n)=n\log n\ $ and beyond, in the limit $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} n a_n \to 0\ $ - so now we are considering whether  $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} (n\log n) a_n \to 0,\ $ I came up with the following proposition:

> **Proposition $\ 1:\ $** If $\ (a_n)_n,\ (b_n)_n,\ $ are positive decreasing sequences such
> that $\ \displaystyle\sum a_n \ $ converges and $\ \displaystyle\sum b_n \ $ diverges, then $\ \frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 0.\ $

The following is a counter-example:

$$b_n = \frac{1}{n\log n},$$

$$\text{ For each } k\in\mathbb{N},\ \text{ let } a_n = \frac{ 1 }{ \left(2^{2^{k}}\right)^2 \log\left( \left(2^{2^{k}}\right)^2 \right) } \text{ for all }\ 2^{2^k} < n\leq 2^{2^{k+1}} = \left(2^{2^{k}}\right)^2 .$$

$$$$

In fact, Proposition 1 with $b_n = \frac{1}{n\log n},$ is the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711615/if-a-n-searrow-0-and-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-infty-does-this-imply-t), which has similar counter-examples.

> **Proposition $\ 2:\ $** If $\ (a_n)_n,\ (b_n)_n,\ $ are positive decreasing sequences, $\ (a_n)_n\ $ is convex, that is, $\ a_n - a_{n+1} \geq a_{n+1} - a_{n+2}\quad \forall\ n,\ $ and $\ \displaystyle\sum  a_n \ $ converges and $\ \displaystyle\sum  b_n \ $ diverges, then $\ \frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 0.\ $

Is this true or false? Tools that could be relevant:

[Cauchy's Condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), in particular, [Schlömilch's_Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Schl%C3%B6milch%27s_Generalization).

[The integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)

[Stolz–Cesàro_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. But the type of counter-example compared to proposition $1$ is different in that this time we let $a_n$ be any function satisfying the properties, and then we choose $b_n$ based on $a_n.$ So for example, the following is a counter-example:

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}, $$

$$\text{ For each } k\in\mathbb{N},\ b_n = \frac{ 1 }{ \left({{2^2}^k}\right)^2 } \text{ if }\ {2^2}^k \leq n < {2^2}^{k+1} = \left({2^2}^k\right)^2.$$

The next natural question is: what if both $\ (a_n)\ $ and $\ (b_n)\ $ are required to be convex? I have asked this as [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582378/if-a-n-n-b-n-n-are-positive-convex-decreasing-sequences-sum-a-n-con).