# Suppose $(a_n),(b_n)$ are decreasing sequences, $\sum a_n$ converges, $\sum b_n$ diverges. $\liminf_{\alpha\to 0^+}\frac{n_a(\alpha)}{n_b(\alpha)}=0?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

> Suppose $(a_n), (b_n)$ are positive, decreasing real sequences, $\displaystyle\sum
>  a_n$ converges, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=0,$ and $ \displaystyle\sum b_n$ diverges. For each $\alpha > 0,$ define
> $f(\alpha)$ to be the least integer $n$ such that $a_n< \alpha.$
> Similarly, define $g(\alpha)$ to be the least integer $m$ such that
> $b_m< \alpha.$ Prove or disprove: $\displaystyle\liminf_{\alpha\to 0^+}
>  \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} = 0.$

This question arose when thinking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582378/if-a-n-n-b-n-n-are-positive-convex-decreasing-sequences-sum-a-n-con), where the counter-examples in the answers are clearly also counter-examples to the proposition, "$\displaystyle\lim_{\alpha\to 0^+} \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} = 0.$"

I can't think of any counter-examples to the above question though. With the examples in the question linked above, I think $\displaystyle\liminf_{\alpha\to 0^+} \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} = 0.$

I guess the standard approach to prove the above question true is proof by contradiction. So suppose $\displaystyle\liminf_{\alpha\to 0^+} \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \neq 0,\implies \displaystyle\liminf_{\alpha\to 0^+} \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} > 0,\ $ that is, $\ \exists\ \varepsilon>0,\ \exists\ t>0,\ $ such that $\frac{f(t')}{g(t')} > \varepsilon\ \forall\ 0<t'<t.\ $ I don't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: Does $b_n$ converge to zero?

Comment: @SungjinKim good point. I have amended this into the question.

Answer (score 0):

If $\liminf_{\alpha\to 0^+} \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} > 0$ then there is an $\epsilon > 0$ and a $\alpha_0 > 0$ such that $\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \ge \epsilon$ for $0 < \alpha \le \alpha_0$. The *idea* is to use summation by parts to show that $\sum b_n$ can be estimated above in terms of $\sum a_n$, and in particular that $\sum b_n < \infty$ in contradiction to the assumption that $\sum b_n$ diverges.

*Remark:* I'll assume that the sequence indices of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ start at $n=1$ and use $\Bbb N$ for the set of *positive* integers $1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Let $(x_k)_{k \ge 1}$ be the *distinct* element of
$$
 \{ a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \} \cup \{ b_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}
$$
in decreasing order and choose some $x_0 > x_1$. Note that $x_k \to 0$.

Let $0 < \delta < \alpha_0$. Let $M$ be the first index with $x_{M} \le \alpha_0$, and let $m$ be the first index with $x_{m+1} \le \delta$. Then
$$ 
\begin{align}
\sum_{b_n > \delta} b_n &= \sum_{k=1}^m  \bigl(g(x_k) - g(x_{k-1})\bigr) x_k\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^m g(x_k) x_k  - x_{k-1} g(x_{k-1}) + g(x_{k-1}) (x_{k-1} - x_k) \\
&= -x_0g(x_0)  + \left(\sum_{k=1}^m g(x_{k-1}) (x_{k-1} - x_k)  \right) +  g(x_m)x_m \\
&= C_1 + \left(\sum_{k=M+1}^m g(x_{k-1}) (x_{k-1} - x_k)  \right) +  g(x_m)x_m
\end{align}
$$
for some constant $C_1$ which does not depend on $\delta$. In the same way we get
$$
\sum_{a_n > \delta} a_n =  C_2 + \left(\sum_{k=M+1}^m f(x_{k-1}) (x_{k-1} - x_k)  \right) +  f(x_m)x_m
$$
for some constant $C_2$ which does not depend on $\delta$. Now $g(x_k) \le \frac 1 \epsilon f(x_k)$ for $k \ge M$, so that
$$
\sum_{b_n > \delta} b_n \le  C_1 - \frac{C_2}{\epsilon} + \frac 1 \epsilon \sum_{a_n > \delta} a_n \, .
$$
This holds for all $\delta > 0$, and we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \le  C_1 - \frac{C_2}{\epsilon} +\frac 1 \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n  < \infty
$$
in contradiction to the assumptions. This proves that
$
\liminf_{\alpha\to 0^+} \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} = 0
$.

Answer (score 0):

Since convergence (or divergence) and summation  of series of absolutely convergent series is invariant under rearrangements, I only consider the case where the series $a$ and $b$ are positive and non increasing in this posting.

---

**Some general facts:**

Consider the space $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}},\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure. Let $\mathcal{c}_0$ denote the space of bounded sequences $a$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a(n)=0$. Notice that the space of absolute convergent series is $L_1(\mu)$ with norm
$$\|f\|_1=\int_\mathbb{N}|f(n)|\mu(dn)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}|f(n)|$$
For any sequence $f$, define
$$d_f(\alpha)=\mu(|f|>\alpha),\qquad \alpha\geq0$$
Notice  that $d_f$ is a right-continuous, monotone non increasing and that $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}d_f(\alpha)=0$ if $d_f(s)<\infty$ for some $s\geq0$.

If $f\in\mathcal{c}_0$ is positive ($f(n)>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N})$ and non increasing, then
\begin{align}
n_f(\alpha):=\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}: f(n)<\alpha\}= d_f(\alpha-)+1, \quad 0\leq \alpha<\|f\|_\infty \tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}

It is known that for $f\in L_1(\mu)$,

1. $\|f\|_1=\int^\infty_0d_f(t)\,dt$,
2. and $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0+}\alpha d_f(\alpha)=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\alpha d_f(\alpha)=0$
   for
   $$\alpha\mu(|f|>\alpha)\leq\int_{|f|>\alpha}|f|\leq\|f\|_1,$$
   the fact that $\|f\|_1=\int^\infty_0 d_f(\alpha)\,dt$, and
   $$\alpha\mu(\alpha)\leq\int^\alpha_{\alpha/2} \mu(|f|>t)\,dt$$

---

**Application to the OP's problem:**

Suppose $f,g$ are positive (not necessarily monotone) sequences such that $f\in L_1(\mu)$, $g\notin L_1(\mu)$, and  such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(n)=0$. Then

3. $\infty=d_f(0)=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0}d_f(\alpha)=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0}d_g(\alpha)=d_g(0)$,
4. $\max\big(d_g(\alpha),d_f(\alpha)\big)=0$ for all $\alpha>\max(\|f\|_\infty,\|g\|_\infty)$.

- If $s:=\liminf_{\alpha\rightarrow0}\frac{d_f(\alpha)}{d_g(\alpha)}>0$, then there is $\alpha_0>0$ such that
  $$\frac{s}{2}d_g(\alpha) <d_f(\alpha), \qquad 0<\alpha<\alpha_0$$
  This implies that
  $$\|g\|_1=\int^\infty_0 d_g(\alpha)\,d\alpha<\infty$$
  in contradiction to $\|g\|_1=\infty$. Therefore,
  \begin{align}
  \liminf_{\alpha\rightarrow0}\frac{d_f(\alpha)}{d_g(\alpha)}=0\tag{5}\label{five}
  \end{align}
- If in addition $f$ and $g$ are also nonincreasing, then by \eqref{zero}, observation [3],  and \eqref{five}
  \begin{align}
  \liminf_{\alpha\rightarrow0}\frac{n_f(\alpha)}{n_g(\alpha)}=0\tag{6}\label{six}
  \end{align}